# Realtime Application using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, websocket, real-time

I am working on a mobile application and require following feature-
When **Admin App user changes status on the admin app, the user on the client app must get it updated in real-time** (as we generally see in real-time delivery apps which show status of delivery). The backend is handled using Spring-boot application.
**I am familiar with the concept of Web Sockets and how to use them on mobile applications**. But I am not familiar with the Web Socket configuration on the backend (Spring Boot Application).
I saw several articles related to **simple chatting web applications** but couldn't find much about such a scenario. Can anybody suggest how can I implement this on the backend, how **exactly Web Socket APIs can be developed using Spring Boot and how the complete flow of data from one mobile to another mobile can be achieved?**

Answer (score 0):

A full description of how to do this is, in my opinion, beyond the scope of a SO answer, so I'll provide some links to resources you can use to build the knowledge instead:

- [Spring WebSockets reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket)
- [Example of a WebSockets app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)
- [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring)